# Export SPARQL query results into json file in sesame

Tags: java, sparql, sesame

I need to export SPARQL query results into JSON using Sesame. Should I use the class `SPARQLResultsJSONWriter`?  How would this be implemented (in Java)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually explained in the Sesame [Repository API](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#The_Repository_API) user documentation, with code examples to demonstrate.

However, to reiterate: once you have prepared a query by using [RepositoryConnection.prepareTupleQuery](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/index.html?org/openrdf/repository/RepositoryConnection.html), you can evaluate the returned [TupleQuery](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/index.html?org/openrdf/query/TupleQuery.html) object in two ways: one is by calling `evaluate()`, in which case the evaluation method will return a TupleQueryResult object. The other is by calling `evaluate(TupleQueryResultHandler)` and passing it a [TupleQueryResultHandler](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/index.html?org/openrdf/query/TupleQueryResultHandler.html) instance, of which SPARQLResultJSONWriter is a subclass. So all you need to is bring the pieces together, like so:

```
RepositoryConnection conn = rep.getConnection();
try {
   // prepare the query
   String queryString = "SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o . }";
   TupleQuery query = conn.prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, queryString);

   // open a file to write the result to it in JSON format
   OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/output.json");
   TupleQueryResultHandler writer = new SPARQLResultJSONWriter(out);

   // execute the query and write the result directly to file
   query.evaluate(writer);  
}
finally {
   conn.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I'm much familiar with it now.